# How to remove window decoration from Firefox 4?

Tags: compiz

Basically I want to know how to remove the window decoration in Firefox 4 using Compiz. I successfully removed window decoration in Opera, I just needed to add this line !(name=opera) in the `Window Decoration` option. However it didn't work as well for when I tried the same thing to remove window decoration from Firefox 4.

So do anyone know how to do that?

**UPDATE**

I found this nice guide how to fix it nicely

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/firefox-4-get-tabs-in-title-bar-like.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the same place you did with Opera you can do this `!(class=Firefox)`, it worked for me just fine.

If you want them both to work like that add `!(name=opera) & !(class=Firefox)`.

Comment: great it worked, any idea why it needed `class`, instead for `name` in this case?

Comment: When using name the value would be "Navigator", but i do not know if it would affect another apps, so i thought class would work better.